# Adding multiple values TXT record on aws ROUTE 53 using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to create multi line TXT record on aws rout53 using nodejs. The issue is I am not able to insert the new line. below is the chunk of code.

```
nike = "verify_sdf5423456tfggg";

  {
     Action: "UPSERT",
       ResourceRecordSet: {
           Name: domain.join("."),
             ResourceRecords: [
                {
                 //here I need a new line after '?all'
                  Value: "\"" + "v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all" + "\"" + "\n" + nike
                }
               ],
               TTL: 300,
               Type: "TXT"
             }
          }
```

The output on TXT record should be like this

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all"
"verify_sdf5423456tfggg"
```

I have tried various options but not able to do this. Can someone please help me here? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I found out. You have to add multiple value to achieve this. for example like below,

```
 {
             Action: "UPSERT",
             ResourceRecordSet: {
               Name: domain.join("."),
               ResourceRecords: [
                {
                  Value: "\"" + "v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all" + "\""    
                },
                {
                  Value: nike   
                }
               ],
               TTL: 300,
               Type: "TXT"
             }
          }
```